# Android override default dialog theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I want to create a custom style for an activity that will look like a dialog. But i want to put this dialog at the top right of the screen, and also set is background to transparent.

I have setted the activity theme to @android:style/Theme.Dialog but now i want to override the existing theme but i have not found this theme in my sdk folder.

Can someone tell me how can i change the default dialog theme?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define Styles for customizing any View.

For example:

```
<style name="Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@android:style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Great. thks for your reply. how do you know what properties have a dialog object? and what type of animation etc.

Comment: @Allrast: to know all available options, you can check out the android source, and look in [styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) and [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml). In this case, for dialogs, checkout themes.xml -> Theme.Dialog. All the attributes defined inside it are usually the ones you can change.

Comment: Does this apply it or I have to additionally set the theme via code or xml, e.g. `theme="@style/Theme.Dialog"`